# Issue when drawing image on canvas on iPad

Tags: ios, image, canvas

I'm working on an HTML5 project, that will run in a WKWebView on iPad.
I'm doing everything programatically.

My WKWebView frame takes the full screen, viewport is 1180x820,
so I set my canvas size and height to 1180x820 too.

Here is my original picture I'd like to display:
[image: Original picture]

But when I'm displaying an 1920x1080 image on my canvas with the drawImage function,
the image does not fit on the screen (obsviously) but is really well displayed (not blurred).

```
_canvasContext.drawImage(imgMenu,0,0,1920,1080).
```

[image: Only part of the picture is displayed]

So I rescale the image when drawing it, still with the drawImage function.
`_canvasContext`.drawImage(imgMenu,0,0,1920/2,1080/2)

[image: Blurred picture]The image fits in the screen, but is blurred.
The downscaling is really really bad (it really could be better, this example is not the worst one).

I already tried the parameters

```
_canvasContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
_canvasContext.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
_canvasContext.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
_canvasContext.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";
```

It does not help.

Maybe I do something wrong, I don't understand what to do.

Screen resolution of my ipad is 2360x1640, so displaying a 1920x1080 picture should not be a problem.

If anyone could help me, that would save my life :)

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: The problem is that I downscale a picture of 1920x1080 to fit in a 1180x820 canvas, but then I display my 1180x820 canvas on a 2360x1640 screen.

Using a 2360x1640 canvas does not help: only a quarter of the canvas is displayed on my iPad (I don't want to scroll).

Comment: You could try using `_canvasContext.scale(0.5)` to scale the canvas down, instead of modifying the image width/height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those annoying and confusing things about canvas. What you need to do is size the canvas using `devicePixelRatio`. This will increase the actual size of the canvas to match the pixel density of the device. This could be 2, or 1.5 etc... a retina screen is often 2.

For drawing your image, the smart way is to support any image size and fit it into the canvas area (usually scaling down). *With a tiny image, this code will scale up and lose resolution.*

```js
const IMAGE_URL = 'https://unsplash.it/1920/1080';

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const _canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

// you will probably want this, unless you want to support many screen sizes in which case you will actually want the window size:
/*
const width = 1180;
const height = 820;
*/

const width = window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight

const ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
// size the canvas to use pixel ratio
canvas.width = Math.round(width * ratio);
canvas.height = Math.round(height * ratio);

// downsize the canvas with css - making it
// retina compatible
canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
canvas.style.height = height + 'px';

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
_canvasContext.fillStyle = 'gray'
_canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function drawImage(url) {
  const img = new Image()
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {

    // find a good scale value to fit the image
    // on the canvas
    const scale = Math.min(
      canvas.width / img.width,
      canvas.height / img.height
    );

    // calculate image size and padding
    const scaledWidth = img.width * scale;
    const scaledHeight = img.height * scale;
    const padX = scaledWidth < canvas.width ? canvas.width - scaledWidth : 0;
    const padY = scaledHeight < canvas.height ? canvas.height - scaledHeight : 0;

    _canvasContext.drawImage(img, padX / 2, padY / 2, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
  })
  img.src = url;
}

drawImage(IMAGE_URL);
```

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

As mentioned in a comment in the code snippet. If your want your canvas to always use 1180x820... be sure to change the width and height variables:

```
  const width = 1180;
  const height = 820;
```

For the purposes of the snippet I used the window size. Which may be better for you if you wish to support other device sizes.